# Webservice object response in android

Tags: java, c#, android, sql, web-services

Im trying to use this webservice I created in c#:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public Student StudentDetails(string sName)
    {

        Student objStd = new Student();


        SqlConnection conn;
        conn = Class1.ConnectionManager.GetConnection();
        conn.Open();

        SqlCommand newCmd = conn.CreateCommand();

        newCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        newCmd.CommandText = "select * from dbo.tblUser where name='" + sName + "'";
        SqlDataReader sdr = newCmd.ExecuteReader();


        if (sdr.Read())
        {
            objStd.id = Int32.Parse(sdr["Id"].ToString());
            objStd.name = sdr["name"].ToString();
            objStd.grade = sdr["grade"].ToString();
        }
        conn.Close();
        sdr.Close();
        return objStd;
    }



    public class Student
    {
        public int id;
        public string name;
        public string grade;
    }
```

which take id and return an object with values.

im trying to call this in android application, like this:

mainactivty.java:

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

boolean timeoutexcep=false,httpexcep=false,generalexcep=false;
    String nam="lama";


String Id,name,grade;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new Persondetails().execute();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

class Persondetails extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.dialog.setMessage("Loading data");
        this.dialog.show();
    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {

        final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
        final String URL = "http://192.168.1.5:90/myWebService.asmx";
        final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/StudentDetails";
        final String METHOD_NAME = "StudentDetails";

        SoapObject request2 = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        request2.addProperty("sName", nam);


        Bean C = new Bean();
        PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
        pi.setName("Bean");
        pi.setValue(C);
        pi.setType(C.getClass());
        request2.addProperty(pi);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope2 = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope2.dotNet = true;
        envelope2.setOutputSoapObject(request2);
        envelope2.addMapping(NAMESPACE, "Bean", new Bean().getClass());
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        androidHttpTransport.debug = true;

        try {
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope2);
            SoapObject response2 = (SoapObject) envelope2.getResponse();


            System.out.println("check Request" + request2);
            System.out.println("check response" + response2);

            envelope2.addMapping(NAMESPACE, "Panchayat",new Bean().getClass());
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope2);
            Bean[] personobj = new Bean[response2.getPropertyCount()];
            Bean beanobj = new Bean();

            for (int j = 0; j < personobj.length; j++) {
                SoapObject pii = (SoapObject) response2.getProperty(j);
                beanobj.Id = Integer.parseInt(pii.getProperty(1).toString());
                beanobj.name = pii.getProperty(2).toString();
                beanobj.grade = pii.getProperty(3).toString();

                personobj[j] = beanobj;
            }

            name=beanobj.name;
            Id=String.valueOf(beanobj.Id);
            grade=beanobj.grade;

        }
        catch(SocketTimeoutException e){
            timeoutexcep=true;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(ConnectException e){
            httpexcep=true;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            generalexcep=true;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
            this.dialog.dismiss();
        }

        if(timeoutexcep){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Unable to connect to server, Please try again later",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else if(httpexcep){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please check your Internet connection",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else if(generalexcep){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please try later",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        else {
            display();
        }
        timeoutexcep=false;httpexcep=false;generalexcep=false;
    }

    private void display() {

        TextView t1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);
        t1.setText(name);
        TextView t2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.palce);
        t2.setText(grade);
        TextView t3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.age);
        t3.setText(Id);
        TextView t4=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.phone);
        t4.setText("COOOL!");
    }
}
 }
```

Bean.java

```
 public class Bean implements KvmSerializable
 {
public int Id;
public String name;
public String grade;


public Bean(){}

public Bean( int Id,String name,String grade)
{
    this.Id=Id;
    this.name=name;
    this.grade=grade;
}

public Object getProperty(int arg0) {
    switch(arg0)
    {
        case 0:
            return Id;
        case 1:
            return name;
        case 2:
            return grade;
    }
    return null;
}

public int getPropertyCount() {
    return 4;
}

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public void getPropertyInfo(int index, Hashtable arg1, PropertyInfo info) {
    switch(index)
    {
        case 0:
            info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
            info.name = "Id";
            break;
        case 1:
            info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
            info.name = "name";
            break;
        case 2:
            info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
            info.name = "grade";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

public void setProperty(int index, Object value) {
    switch(index)
    {
        case 0:
            Id = Integer.parseInt(value.toString());
            break;
        case 1:
            name = value.toString();
            break;
        case 2:
            grade = value.toString();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
}
```

but this always returns a toast with try later, I don't know what is wrong with my code? can someone help please?

Comment: Remove try catch for a moment and see what error you getting .post the stack trace

Comment: @NitinMesta I got multiple errors if I do so ..